# JavaFX validation understanding

Tags: validation, javafx, listener, textfield, digits

I found this code online that stops a user from entering anything but a number in a `TextField`. I want to use it in my code for homework but I do not understand what is happening. Is anyone able to help me understand WHY it works? Thank you.

```
valueTextField.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
       @Override
       public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
            if (!newValue.matches("\\d{0,9}([\\.]\\d{0,9})?")) {
                valueTextField.setText(oldValue);
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: This is an onchange listener, so when the value is changed this function will be executed. Since it is an on change listener it gives you both your new and old value as arguments. In this case this method is checking to see that the new value is a number using regex. If it is not an integer it sets it back to the old value.

Comment: Note that, while this may work, using a `ChangeListener` on the `text` property is not the correct way to filter input—you should be using a [`TextFormatter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html).

Comment: @Slaw I saw that about ```TextFormatter``` but couldn’t find a simple or clear enough example as I am very new to Java and JavaFX.

Comment: How would I allow a negative sign (-) to be used for adding negative values?

Answer (score -1):

this might be a brute force approach without using regex. it just tries to cast the input as target value. if it fails, the old value will be set (according to your approach).

```
alpha.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable, String oldValue, String newValue) {
                Double dou = 0.0;
                boolean valid = false;
                try {
                    dou = Double.parseDouble(newValue);
                    if (dou >= 0 && dou <= 1) { // some conditions if you need a specific range
                        valid = true;
                    }

                } catch(Exception e) {}
                if (valid) {
                    alphaInput = dou;
                    Qnet.setAlpha(dou);
                    alpha.setText(dou.toString());
                } else {
                    alpha.setText(oldValue);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: no - it's _wrong_ to change a property when being notified on its change. textformatter is the way to go